# How to deploy a hibernate application on Tomcat?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I have a GWT-Hibernate-JPA Application that runs fine from within Eclipse Jetty included in GWT.
I now tried to deploy my `war` to a local tomcat installation. Manger console is running, but my app is not deployed with following error:

```
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.5.2\webapps\myapp: javax/persistence/Converter
```

What might I be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it is necessary to copy the hibernate-jpa (`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Draft-16.jar`) library to `CATALINE_HOME\lib`. It is not sufficient to have it in the `war\WEB-INF\lib` as one would expect.